# How to disable clipboard in Vim

Tags: vim, clipboard

`vim` over ssh to a linux system is taking a very long time at startup.
Profiling with `vim --startuptime` I found that the problem is setting up the clipboard:

```
clock   elapsed: 
5042.066  5041.140: setup clipboard
```

Is there a way to disable this step?
I never use that anyway and I'd rather have a quicker startup.

Comment: recompile ssh without xorg support?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

found solution with some more googling:

```
set clipboard=exclude:.*
```

Now the startup time is quick!

Comment: Do you know how to also set "clipboard=unnamedplus" at the same time?